# Calculating bid price from total cost

Tags: algorithm, math

I have to following problem to solve. I have to calculate the bidding price from a total price. For example, a client wants to pay 2000$ as a total price, but from this price, there are added costs:

-usage price which is 10% from the bidding price with a minimum of 10$ and a maximum of 50$

-seller price: 2% from bidding price

-added price: 5$ for a bid between 1 and 500
              10$ for a bid between 501 and 1000
              15$ for a bid between 1001 and 3000
              20$ for a bid over 3000$

-storing cost: 100$

from all this, I have to calculate the bidding price for a total of 2000$, for example. I kind of have no clue of how this can be done. Can anyone give me some hints or pieces of answer of what the algorithm should be?

EDIT: ok I got how to calculate the algebra, now where i'm stuck is how to write the algorithm in code or pseudo-code. Anyone got a hint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can express all those costs as a function of the bid price. Generate a giant equation that is the sum of all those functions and solve for a particular final value, e.g.:

```
usage cost(bid) = PIN(bid*0.10, 10, 50)
seller cost(bid) = bid*.02
added cost(bid) = PIN(ceiling(bid/500)*5, 5, 10) + PIN(ceiling((bid - 1000)/2000)*5, 0, 10)
storing cost(bid) = 100
```

So the final cost is something like:

```
final cost(bid) = PIN(bid*.1, 10, 50) + pin(ceiling(bid/500)*5, 5, 20) + PIN(ceiling((bid - 1000)/2000)*10, 0, 20) + bid*.02 + 100 + bid
```

Solve for a particular value and you're done.

For example, if you want the total cost to be $2000:

```
2000 = PIN(bid*.1, 10, 50) + pin(ceiling(bid/500)*5, 5, 10) + PIN(ceiling((bid - 1000)/2000)*5, 0, 10) + bid*.02 + 100 + bid.
```

Bid must be at least > 1500 and < 2000, which works out nicely since we can make those PIN sections constant:

```
2000 = 50 + 10 + 5 + 100 + bid*1.02
1835 = bid*1.02
bid = 1799.0196078431372549019607843137
```

The PIN expressions are the hardest to factor out, so you might have to guess a few times until you get something that narrows down the range of bids you want to calculate.

Comment: if I understand you right, I think you're not understanding me .. :P I don't have the bid price as for a start. All I have is the TOTAL price and what I have to calculate is the BID price. Correct me if i'm wrong. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Right. You want to solve for bid given that final cost(bid) is some known value. You gave 2000 as an example final cost, so you can work backwards from that to determine the bid.

Comment: I'm going to add your specific example to better explain what to do.

Comment: thanks a lot for that clear answer, but what exactly is PIN? sorry english is not my first language.

Comment: It takes the value and makes at it least as big as the second parameter and at most the third parameter. I.e., pin(x, 0, 1) will return the closest number to x that is greater than 0 and less than 1.

Comment: Also known as "clip(x, a, b)".  pin(x, a, b) = min(b, max(a, x)).

Comment: ok I fully understand it, but now how can I have a har time putting this in pseudo code or code. May I get a hint?

Comment: I have no idea; most spreadsheet programs should be able to do it.